# The method openSession() in the type SessionFactory is not applicable for the arguments (Connection)

Tags: java, hibernate

When I migrated Hibernate 3.2.7 to Hibernate 4.3.5, Java7 to Java8 and Tomcat7 to Tomcat8, i got the 2 errors below. Please provide some resolution for this issue.

1. `The method openSession() in the type SessionFactory is not applicable for the arguments (AuditLogInterceptor)`  HibernateUtil.java
2. `The method connection() is undefined for the type Session` --   AuditLogInterceptor.java

**HibernateUtil.java**

```
public class HibernateUtil {


private static Configuration configuration;
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static final ThreadLocal threadSession = new ThreadLocal();
private static final ThreadLocal threadTransaction = new ThreadLocal();
private static final ThreadLocal threadInterceptor = new ThreadLocal();

static {
    try {
        System.out.println("inside hibernate util before calling annotation configuration");
        configuration = new AnnotationConfiguration();
        System.out.println("inside hibernate util after calling annotation configuration before building sessionFactory");
        // sessionFactory = configuration.configure().buildSessionFactory();
        // hibernate 3.5.6 jar update version code
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                configuration.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        System.out.println("inside hibernate util after calling annotation configuration after building sessionFactory");
        System.out.println("static intializer of HibenrateUtil");
        if(sessionFactory == null){
            System.out.println("session factory is null");
        }else{

            System.out.println("session factory is not null");  
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}   

public static Session getSession() throws HibernateException{
    //System.out.println("inside getSession method");   

    Session s = (Session) threadSession.get();
    try {
        //System.out.println("inside try  getSession method");  

        //if( s == null){
            //System.out.println("session is null");    
        //}

        if (s == null || !s.isOpen()) {
            //System.out.println("Opening new Session for this thread.");
            AuditLogInterceptor interceptor = new AuditLogInterceptor();

                **s = sessionFactory.openSession(interceptor);**                
                interceptor.setSession(s);
            }
            threadSession.set(s);
        //System.out.println("session :"+s);
    } catch (HibernateException ex) {
        throw new HibernateException(ex);
    }
    return s;
}
```

**AuditLogUtil.java**

```
public class AuditLogUtil{


public static void LogIt(String action,
    IAuditLog entity, Connection conn) throws Exception{
    SessionServiceImpl sessionServiceImpl=new SessionServiceImpl();
    TbMasUsers tbMasUsers=(TbMasUsers) sessionServiceImpl.getUserInSession();
    Integer loingEmpId=Integer.parseInt(tbMasUsers.getIntEmpId().getStrEmpId());

     Session tempSession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession(conn);

    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("null")
        AuditLog auditRecord = new AuditLog(action,entity.getLogDeatil()
                , new Date(),entity.getId(), entity.getClass().toString(),loingEmpId);
        tempSession.save(auditRecord);
        tempSession.flush();

    } finally { 
        tempSession.close();    

    }

}
```

}

Comment: hmm the way you are configuring the sessionFactory does not look so proper , are you describing somewhere the driver class name ? or at least the initial datasource ? because hibernate , will perform some validations between the mapped POJOs and the corresponding tables at startup , which from your configuration wont happen as it is not having a proper connection

Answer (score 0):

try doing like this might this help:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration=configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

If you are not providing the hibernate configuration location. How the `Configuration` wil load the settings of the `hibernate.cfg.xml`

Comment: yes...i changed code ..im getting issue with line.                                          = sessionFactory.openSession(interceptor)

Comment: Where is your getSessionFactory method in HibernateUtil?

Comment: getSessionfactory()  getter method is added in the code

Comment: AuditLogInterceptor interceptor = new AuditLogInterceptor();    
    
    s = sessionFactory.openSession(interceptor);
    interceptor.setSession(s);

Comment: only problem with above sessionFactory.openSession(interceptor) method..its was working in hibernate 3.6. now hibernate 4.3.1 is not working ..pls let me know anybody have idea or solution??

Comment: There is no such "openSessionFactory(Interceptor inteceptor)" method in "SessionFactory" in Hibernate 4.x